# Difference between Lync basic and Advanced when using Lync SDK?

Tags: lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I am planning to develop an communication apps based on Lync SDK. I understood that in order to run my application, i have to install lync client in the computer. This is where the following question arises

1. Is it possible to develop advanced features (that is available when installing Lync advanced) by using Lync SDK with Lync basic as client?
2. What is the difference between Lync basic and Lync advanced when using Lync SDK?
3. Should i install Lync Advanced to use the advanced features using Lync SDK?

It would be helpful if someone could tell me the difference?

Regards,
Raja

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty much no difference between the Lync Basic Client and the Lync Client when using the Lync Client SDK.

I've only found one very small difference that hit me, Lync Basic doesn't support the "PIN to Gallery" feature.  If you call the "PIN to Gallery" API, it will throw and the API doesn't tell you it's not supported.

The only other limitation of Lync Basic I've hit is that you can't configure any forwards.  But this is more of a client configuration rather than API access limitation.

Everything else I've done with the Lync Client SDK has worked fine between the Lync Basic and the Full Lync Clients.